# What is the error I am facing when I am installing Django via PIP in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, pip

On my OSX 10.10.2, in a virtualenv, I tried to install Django via pip using the command:

```
pip install django
```

And this the responds I got:

```
Collecting django
  Downloading Django-1.7.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4MB)
    100% |################################| 7.4MB 58kB/s 
Installing collected packages: django

  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/qmbp/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/Users/qmbp/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 347, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/Users/qmbp/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 549, in install
      **kwargs
    File "/Users/qmbp/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in install
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "/Users/qmbp/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 963, in move_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/Users/qmbp/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 266, in move_wheel_files
      clobber(source, dest, False, fixer=fixer, filter=filter)
    File "/Users/qmbp/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 212, in clobber
      shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
    File "/Users/qmbp/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 109, in copyfile
      with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/qmbp/.virtualenvs/demo/bin/django-admin.py'
```

I guess the issue is caused as I did not prefix sudo to the command. But I read that it was a good idea to use sudo in OSX. And that is why virtualenv is encouraged as sudo is not needed inside it.
Here is a screenshot of my files as I could not find the "env" in the bin folder.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to activate your venv.

Try:

```
source path_to_your_venv/bin/activate
pip install django
```

Comment: sorry, but a quick question. How to find the path of the venv?? 
FYI, I was already in the venv, I did workon <name_of_venv> before running the pip install

Comment: In my path_to_your_venv/bin/, there is nothing named env